# Wrap 3 divs in one with jQuery

Tags: jquery

I need to wrap 3 divs into one using jQuery.

```
<div class="one"></div><div class="two"></div><div class="three"></div>
```

into this

```
<div class="wrap"><div class="one"></div><div class="two"></div><div class="three"></div></div>
```

How can I do that please?

Many Thanks for your help in advance

Answer (score 29, accepted):

```
$('.one, .two, .three').wrapAll('<div class="wrap">');
```

or

```
$('.one, .two, .three').wrapAll( $('<div>').addClass('wrap') );
```

Reference: http://docs.jquery.com/Manipulation/wrapAll

Comment: I edited my answer a few times as this was the first time I used jQuery.prototype.wrapAll fyi.

Comment: oh, someone managed to 1 second before I hit delete. Oh well.

Comment: @meder. if all the three divs are generated on the fly. how would that approach work. e-g. $(.test).append(<div></div>).append(<a></a>).append(<p></p>).appendTo("body"); how would you wrap all the three div, a and p into one div.