# Wrap each three div to one

Tags: javascript, jquery

Consider we have:

```
<div class "parent">
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  // And Even More....
</div>
```

I need to **Wrap each 3 or fewer (2 , 1), element into the ONE**, while I don't know the count of child nodes. The result I need is something like:

```
<div class "parent">
  <div class "middle">
    <div class="child"></div>
    <div class="child"></div>
    <div class="child"></div>
  </div>
  <div class "middle">
    <div class="child"></div>
    <div class="child"></div>
    <div class="child"></div>
  </div>
  <div class "middle">
    <div class="child"></div>
  </div>
  // And Even More....
</div>
```

How to use `.wrapAll()` or any other method to do this?

A better version of the question would be: How to Select `div`'s 3 by 3? as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1526198) post is showing how to wrap them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var divs = $(".parent div.child");
var divs_length = divs.length;
for(var i = 0; i < divs_length; i+=3) {
  divs.slice(i, i+3)
     .wrapAll('<div class="middle"></div>');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Always try to get the total elements into variable. `.length` value remains constant, it will not change for every iteration.

```
 var childs = $("div.parent").children();
 var totElements = childs.length;
 var i = -3;

 while( (i += 3) < totElements)
     childs.slice(i,i+3).wrapAll( "<div class='middle' />");
```